# Uninstalled package causing conflict on system upgrade with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I'm on Arch Linux.

I once attempted to install `aur/teams-for-linux` with `yay` which installed `nodejs-lts-gallium` as a dependency. Since some things didn't work out and I found that teams could be used well in Chroimium, I stopped installing or uninstalled (I don't remember which) `aur/teams-for-linux` and replaced `nodejs-lts-gallium` with `nodejs` (`sudo pacman -S nodejs`). Now, when I run `pacman -Qs nodejs`, `nodejs-lts-gallium` isn't listed. However, I'm trying to run `sudo pacman -Su` but am getting `nodejs-lts-gallium and nodejs are in conflict. Remove nodejs? [y/N]`.

How do I remove the `nodejs-lts-gallium` artifacts causing the conflict?

Comment: Have you tried `pacman -R nodejs-lts-gallium` ?

Comment: @Fang Yes, I get `error: target not found: nodejs-lts-gallium` since it's not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After proceeding with the system upgrade, I found out that it was conflicting because `nodejs-lts-gallium` was being required by another package (`bloodhound`) which previously didn't require that version. Seems it wasn't a residual issue from `teams-for-linux`, just an unfortunate & confusing coincidence.